# Oracle SQL запрос

Tags: sql, oracle

Необходимо создать запрос, выдающий список предметов и количество оценок 3, 4 и 5 по этим предметам соответственно.

Есть две таблицы:

- таблица, описывающая **предметы**: **id предмета**, **название предмета**;
- таблица, хранящая **оценки**: **id предмета**, **оценка по предмету**.

Answer (score 4):

```
select p.предмет, 
sum(case o.оценка when 5 then 1 else 0 end) "5", 
sum(case o.оценка when 4 then 1 else 0 end) "4", 
sum(case o.оценка when 3 then 1 else 0 end) "3" 
from предметы p inner join оцeнки o on o.id=p.id 
group by p.предмет;
```

[CASE](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_statement.html)

Comment: Только скобки надо закрывать)

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.предмет, 
       o.оценка, 
       count(1) as количество 
from   предметы p 
inner  join оцeнки o 
on     o.id=p.id 
and    оценка in ('3', '4', '5')
group  by p.предмет, o.оценка
```